# How to bookmark and restore dynamically added modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to save and restore an app that uses modules which render UI outputs dynamically.

I hoped the bookmarking function would work with the app and I added the `bookmarkButton` and enabled bookmarking using `enableBookmarking = "server"`. I've also made the ui a function. I learned that [bookmarking works with modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-modules.html), but I'm unable to find a way to get it working with dynamically created UI inputs and outputs. Only the last input and output are restored. The others are not restored.

Example app:

```
library(shiny)

histogramUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars)),
    numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = 10, min = 1)),
    column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
}

ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    actionButton("add", "Add"),
    div(id = "add_here")
    )
  }

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    histogramServer(paste0("hist_", input$add))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", input$add)))
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Only the last input and plot output are restored:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would expect all module instances to be restored, but as you pointed out, only the last one is restored due to `add`button restoration.
As a workaround, you could store the module instances list stored in `state$exclude` with `onBookmark` and re-create the instances of the module with `onRestore`.
`histogramUI` was modified in order to accept `var,bins` as new parameters for creation of the modules.
Another important point is to use `setBookmarkExclude` so that the `add` button doesn't create the last module at restoration. As the button isn't anymore bookmarked, it's value should be also be saved with `onBookmark`.

Try:

```
library(shiny)


histogramUI <- function(id,var,bins) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                     numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = bins, min = 1)),
             column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
  
}


ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    actionButton("add", "Add Histogram"),
    div(id = "add_here")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  add_id <- reactiveVal(0)  # To save 'add' button state
  setBookmarkExclude('add') # Don't add new module at restoration
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    histogramServer(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()),'mpg',10))
  })
  
  
  onBookmark(function(state) { 
    modules <- state$exclude
    state$values$modules <- modules[grepl("hist",modules)] # only 'hist' (without 'add')
    state$values$add <- state$input$add + add_id() # add button state
  })
  
  onRestore(function(state){
    # Restore 'add' last state
    add_id(state$values$add)

    # Restore 'hist' modules
    modules <- state$values$modules
    if (length(modules)>0) {
      for (i in 1:(length(modules))) {
          histogramServer(modules[i])
          insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(modules[i],paste0(modules[i],"-var"),paste0(modules[i],"-bin")))
      }
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Comment: Excellent! When I did 3 charts in this order (mpg, cyl, disp) and restored it, I got (disp, mpg, cyl). In a way it is partially reversed. It would be great if we can find a way to restore the right order too. I'll have a look at it as well.

Comment: Now fully working : I used `onRestored` instead of `onRestore`, hence the creation of the first module before restoration of the others.

Comment: This looks good! Can you please explain why do we need to loop through the bins in this for loop ` for (i in 1:length(hist_bin)) { . . . ` ?

Comment: Each module creates two inputs : `hist_x_bin` and `hist_x_var`. The code just loops in all modules except the last one which is automatically restored.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it:

```
library(shiny); library(purrr)

histogramUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(ns("var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars)),
                         numericInput(ns("bins"), "bins", value = 10, min = 1)),
                 column(8, plotOutput(ns("hist"))))
    )
}

histogramServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        vals <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
        
        data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
        output$hist <- renderPlot({
            hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
        }, res = 96)
        
        #to avoid inputs resetting after adding another.
        if(length(vals) != 0) {
            updateSelectInput(session, 'var', "Variable", choices = names(mtcars), selected = vals$var)
            updateNumericInput(session, 'bins', "bins", value = input$bins, min = 1,)
        } 
    })
}

ui <- function(request){
    fluidPage(
        bookmarkButton(),
        actionButton("add", "Add"),
        uiOutput('histogram_module') 
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        #the server module
        map(1:input$add, ~histogramServer(paste0("hist_", .x)))
        #the ui module
        output$histogram_module <- renderUI({ map(1:input$add, ~histogramUI(id = paste0("hist_", .x))) })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```