# How to loop through bookmark state inputs and restore in the right order?

Tags: r, shiny

I have 3 modules to get histograms, boxplots and tables. The reactivity and saving the state works great, but I'm unable to restore them in the right order.

I've tried `onRestored` which jumbles the order or groups the modules. I've also tried to reset the inputs so that further saving and reloading doesn't change the order. `onRestore` is close but it reorders the output in the reverse order.

```
library(shiny)
library(janitor)

histogramUI <- function(id,var,bins) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                     numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = bins, min = 1)),
             column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
}


tableUI <- function(id,var,bins) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                    
             column(8, tableOutput(NS(id, "tab")))))
  )
}


tableServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$tab <- renderTable({
      tabyl(data(), main = input$var)
    })
  })
}



boxUI <- function(id,var) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var2"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                    
             column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "box"))))
  ))
}


boxServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var2]])
    output$box <- renderPlot({
      boxplot(data(), main = input$var2)
    })
  })
}


ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    actionButton("add", "Add Histogram"),
    actionButton("add2", "Add Boxplot"),
    actionButton("add3", "Add Table"),
    div(id = "add_here")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    bins <- 10
    histogramServer(paste0("hist_", input$add))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", input$add),input$var,bins))#}
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add2, {
     boxServer(paste0("box_", input$add2))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = boxUI(paste0("box_", input$add2), input$var2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add3, {
    tableServer(paste0("tab_", input$add3))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = tableUI(paste0("tab_", input$add3), input$var))
  })
  
  
  
  onRestored(function(state){
    hist_var <- stringr::str_extract(names(state$input),'hist.*var')
    hist_var <- sort(hist_var[!is.na(hist_var)])
    
    hist_bin <- stringr::str_extract(names(state$input),'hist.*bin')
    hist_bin <- sort(hist_bin[!is.na(hist_bin)])
    
    box_var <- stringr::str_extract(names(state$input),'box.*var2')
    box_var <- sort(box_var[!is.na(box_var)])
    
    tab_var <- stringr::str_extract(names(state$input),'tab.*var')
    tab_var <- sort(tab_var[!is.na(tab_var)])
    
    print(hist_var)
    print(box_var)
    print(tab_var)
    
    if (length(hist_var)>1) {
      for (i in 1:(length(hist_var)-1)) {
        histogramServer(paste0("hist_", i))
        insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", i),state$input$hist_var[i],state$input$hist_bin[i]))
      }
    }
    
    
    if (length(box_var)>1) {
      for (i in 1:(length(box_var)-1)) {
        boxServer(paste0("box_", i))
        insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = boxUI(paste0("box_", i),state$input$box_var[i]))
      }
    }
    
    
    if (length(tab_var)>1) {
      for (i in 1:(length(tab_var)-1)) {
        tableServer(paste0("tab_", i))
        insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = tableUI(paste0("tab_", i),state$input$tab_var[i]))
      }
    }
    
    
    hist_var <- NULL
    hist_bin <- NULL
    box_var <- NULL
    tab_var <- NULL
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `onBookmark` to save `state$exclude` which gives the order of the modules.
The buttons should also be excluded from bookmarking with `setBookmarkExclude` :

```
library(shiny)
library(janitor)

histogramUI <- function(id,var,bins) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                     numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = bins, min = 1)),
             column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
  
}


tableUI <- function(id,var,bins) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                     
                     column(8, tableOutput(NS(id, "tab")))))
  )
}


tableServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$tab <- renderTable({
      tabyl(data(), main = input$var)
    })
  })
  
}



boxUI <- function(id,var) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(column( 4, selectInput(NS(id, "var2"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars),selected=var),
                     
                     column(8, plotOutput(NS(id, "box"))))
    ))
  
}


boxServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var2]])
    output$box <- renderPlot({
      boxplot(data(), main = input$var2)
    })
  })
  
}


ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    actionButton("add", "Add Histogram"),
    actionButton("add2", "Add Boxplot"),
    actionButton("add3", "Add Table"),
    div(id = "add_here")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  setBookmarkExclude(c('add','add2','add3'))
  add_id <- reactiveVal(0)
  add2_id <- reactiveVal(0)
  add3_id <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    bins <- 10
    histogramServer(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", input$add+add_id()),input$var,bins))#}
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add2, {
    boxServer(paste0("box_", input$add2+add2_id())) #changed add_id() to add2_id()
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = boxUI(paste0("box_", input$add2+add2_id()), input$var2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add3, {
    tableServer(paste0("tab_", input$add3+add3_id()))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = tableUI(paste0("tab_", input$add3+add3_id()), input$var))
  })
  onBookmark(function(state) { 
    state$values$modules <- state$exclude
    state$values$add <- state$input$add + add_id()
    state$values$add2 <- state$input$add2 + add2_id()
    state$values$add3 <- state$input$add3 + add3_id()
  })
  
  onRestore(function(state){
    add_id(state$values$add)
    add2_id(state$values$add2)
    add3_id(state$values$add3)
    modules <- state$values$modules
    if (length(modules)>1) {
      for (i in 1:(length(modules))) {
        if (substr(modules[i],1,4)=='hist') {
          histogramServer(modules[i])
          insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(modules[i],paste0(modules[i],"-var"),paste0(modules[i],"-bin")))
        }
        if (substr(modules[i],1,3)=='box') {
          boxServer(modules[i])
          insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = boxUI(modules[i],paste0(modules[i],"-var")))
        }
        if (substr(modules[i],1,3)=='tab') {
          tableServer(modules[i])
          insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = tableUI(modules[i],paste0(modules[i],"-var")))
        }
        
        
      }
    }
    
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Comment: Is also a general answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973185/how-to-bookmark-and-restore-dynamically-added-modules/68008489#68008489

Comment: I love this idea of indexing. It seemed to work great, except when reloading the last module. When I added modules in this order -- "hist_1" "box_1"  "tab_1"  "hist_2" "hist_3" "box_2"  "box_3"  "tab_2"  "tab_3" -- I got this error/warning: 
Warning: Error in .subset2: attempt to select less than one element in get1index.

I was also wondering what modules[i], 1, 4 (or 3) do. Does it access the index by length of characters? I was thinking 4 = "hist", 3 = "box", 3 = "tab". I may be completely wrong.

Comment: I am noticing that it is adding a blank module each at the end. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: It's a bit more complex for many modules than my initial guess : trying to find a workaround...